# Should I use bit-shift or division?

Tags: performance, compiler-optimization

Wikipedia says that for division by powers of 2

> Because bit shifts are often much faster operations than division, replacing a division by a shift in this way can be a helpful step in program optimization.[5] However, for the sake of software portability and readability, it is often best to write programs using the division operation and trust in the compiler to perform this replacement.

Can I trust the compiler? Which compilers (especially C compilers and the java compiler) will replace /2^k with >>k?

Comment: Write whichever code is most readable and understandable. Don't prematurely optimise, especially at the cost of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For signed types division and right shift are different operations from compiler's point of view even if you know that the value is non-negative, unless it's known at compile time and the compiler is able to make use of it.

For unsigned types I believe all decent modern compilers will change division to shift. For example, for this code:

```c
unsigned my_div(unsigned x) {
    return x / 32;
}

unsigned my_shift(unsigned x) {
    return x >> 5;
}
```

[GCC](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g490,options:'-O2',source:'unsigned+my_div(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+/+32%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+my_shift(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+%3E%3E+5%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) and [Clang](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang341,options:'-O2',source:'unsigned+my_div(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+/+32%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+my_shift(unsigned+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+%3E%3E+5%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) produce identical same assembly output for both functions.

(Note the [difference](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g490,options:'-O2',source:'int+my_div(int+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+/+32%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+my_shift(int+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+%3E%3E+5%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) when the functions take `int` instead of `unsigned`)

So, generally you should use plain division because it's guaranteed to be correct. You should replace it to right shift only if:

1. It noticeably increases performance of your program
2. The operand can't be negative (or you really know what you are doing)